# What is wrong in my query?

Tags: mysql

My query is not working, MySQL says that:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CASE WHEN Concepte='01. Ingressos per les activitats' AND
>   Subconcepte='b) Pre' at line 2

And the code:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable
CASE 
    WHEN Concepte='01. Ingressos per les activitats' AND Subconcepte='b) Prestacions de serveis' THEN
        IF Cod_Proj='PR17%' THEN Procedencia='Procedents nova generacio'
        ELSE Procedencia='Procedents cartera'
        END IF
    WHEN Concepte='01. Ingressos per les activitats' AND Subconcepte='e) Subvencions oficials a les activitats' THEN
        IF Cod_Proj='PR17%' THEN Procedencia='Procedents nova generacio'
        ELSE Procedencia='Procedents cartera'
        END IF
END CASE
```

Comment: It's just `END` not `END CASE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Syntax must be:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN Concepte='01. Ingressos per les activitats' AND Subconcepte='b) Prestacions de serveis' THEN
        CASE WHEN Cod_Proj='PR17%' THEN Procedencia='Procedents nova generacio'
        ELSE Procedencia='Procedents cartera'
        END
    WHEN Concepte='01. Ingressos per les activitats' AND Subconcepte='e) Subvencions oficials a les activitats' THEN
        CASE WHEN Cod_Proj='PR17%' THEN Procedencia='Procedents nova generacio'
        ELSE Procedencia='Procedents cartera'
        END 
END 
FROM sometable
```

`SELECT` values to select `from` table

Comment: @bimmer55 The whole message please

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Cod_Proj='PR17%' THEN Procedencia='Procedents nova generacio' ELSE Proc' at line 4

Comment: replace the inner IF with a CASE

Comment: Thank you @Jens I tried your query, but now Im getting this message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; WHEN Concepte='01. Ingressos per les activitats' AND Subconcepte='e) Subv' at line 6